# What is the scope of templates bindings in a directive without a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bnjasim/cx957y3x/) is a simple angular application. It shows/hides a text based on user clicking a button.

```
<div ng-controller="exampleController as ctrl">
  <example></example>
</div>


app.controller('exampleController', function () {});
app.directive('example', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-click=\"clickMe()\">Click me</button>',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.clickMe = function () {
            scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
        };
    }
  };
});
```

When I remove the controller it doesn't work. Note that the directive creates an isolate scope, so my understanding is that it doesn't depend on the controllers scope.

```
<div>
  <example></example>
</div>

app.directive('example', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-click=\"clickMe()\">Click me</button>',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.clickMe = function () {
            scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
        };
    }
  };
});
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But anyways you should have ng-app

```
<body ng-app="demo">
    <div>
        <example></example>
    </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module("demo", [])    

app.directive('example', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-click=\"clickMe()\">Click me</button>',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.clickMe = function () {
                scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx957y3x/1/)

Comment: Missed that completely :) Thanks for the help. I was going crazy over it!